# Query for exact match of users in a conversation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a conversation table, and a user conversation table.

```
CONVERSATION
Id, Subject, Type

USERCONVERSATION
Id, UserId, ConversationId
```

I need to do a SQL Query based on a list of UserIds. So, if I have three UserIds for the same ConversationId, I need to perform a query where if I provide the same three userIds, it will return the ConversationId where they match exactly.

Comment: Do you want the conversations involving _only_ the three users, or that involved the three users _and any number of additional users_?

Comment: Only those three users. Think of it like a phone message. If I start a conversation with 3 people, those 3(or n) people get entered into the UserConversation table with the same conversationId. If I then start a brand new conversation, which happens to have the same 3(or n) people, instead of creating 3 new entries, it will return the conversationId, and then the new message can be added to the existing conversation

Comment: By the way, if you're designing the database, I would critique the fact that you use 'Id' as a column name instead of including the table name such as `Conversation.ConversationID`, since then columns in different tables that mean the same thing have different names. Also, the USERCONVERSATION table probably doesn't need an Id column. It's a many-to-many join table and these almost NEVER need their own IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the same user can't be in a UserConversation twice:

```
SELECT ConversationID
FROM UserConversation
GROUP BY ConversationID
HAVING
   Count(UserID) = 3 -- this isn't necessary but might improve performance
   AND Sum(CASE WHEN UserID IN (1, 2, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 3
```

This also works:

```
SELECT ConversationID
FROM
   UserConversation UC
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
   ) U (UserID) ON UC.UserID = U.UserID
GROUP BY ConversationID
HAVING
   Count(U.UserID) = 3
   AND Count(UC.UserID) = 3
```

If you find that performance is poor with either of these queries then a two-step method could help: First find all conversations containing *at least* the desired parties, then from that set exclude those that contain any others. Indexes of course will make a big difference.

Getting rid of the ID column from UserConversation will improve performance by getting more rows per page, thus more data per read (about 50% more!). If your Id column is not only the PK but also the clustered index, then immediately go change the clustered index to `ConversationId, UserId` (or vice versa, depending on the most common usage)!

If you need help with performance post a comment and I'll try to help you.

P.S. Here's another wild idea but it may not perform as well (though things can surprise you sometimes):

```
SELECT
   Coalesce(C.ConversationID, UC.ConversationID) ConversationID
   -- Or could be Min(C.ConversationID)
FROM
   Conversation C
   CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
   ) U (UserID)
   FULL JOIN UserConversation UC
      ON C.ConversationID = UC.ConversationID
      AND U.UserID = UC.UserID
GROUP BY Coalesce(C.ConversationID, UC.ConversationID)
HAVING Count(*) = Count(U.UserID)
```

Comment: I would be interested in your thoughts on improving performance

Comment: @micky I posted some things, what do you think about them? Can you remove `Id` from `UserConversation`? What are the clustered and nonclustered indexes on the `UserConversation` table? Will you be querying `UserConversation` more often knowing the `ConversationID` or a `UserID`? Do testing on the queries I gave you to see what works the best. If you post the results of all I've said I'll help you more later... I have to go now!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was wrong, unfortunately...
I strongly suggest to use one of [Erik's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275238/multiple-ids-in-table-sql-query/6275791#6275791)...

Regards

Comment: @mickyjtwin This answer doesn't satisfy your requirements. It will return conversations that involved the three users *and any additional number of users*.

Comment: @Erik - how so? if you put number of users in `@numberOfUsersIds` then it will find only those where specified users participate..

Comment: Because your WHERE clause excludes those other users, so the Count will max out at the users in the list, without counting additional users that were excluded. Try this query and see that it returns a row when it should not since UserID 4 was part of the conversation: `SELECT ConversationID FROM (SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 4) UserConversation (ConversationID, UserID) WHERE UserID IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY ConversationID HAVING Count(UserID) = 3`