# TSQL Query Where All Records Must Exists to Return A Record

Tags: c#, t-sql, select, join

I am not sure even how to ask this question.

I have a table of tags:

```
TagId  Tag
-----  -----
1      Fruit
2      Meat
3      Grain
```

I have a table of events:

```
EventId   Event
-------   -----------
1         Eating Food
2         Buying Food
```

What I need to do is bring back only Events that have all selected tags associated with it.

If three tags are selected then only show event that have all three.

For example:

Mapping Table

```
EventId   TagId
-------   -----
1         1
1         3
2         1
```

If I write a query like this:

```
select * from MapTable where where tagId in (1,3)
```

This will return Eating Food and Buying Food.

But what I need to do is bring back events that have both tags 1 and 3.  This means that the only event in this case I would return would be Eating Food as it has both selected tags.

I was wondering if this can be done in TSQL or if I will have to use the business layer to translate it into the object to return back to the GUI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a very similar question yesterday: [Query for exact match of users in a conversation in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275238/query-for-exact-match-of-users-in-a-conversation-in-sql-server)

basically you can do this:

```
DECLARE @NumTags INT = 2

SELECT EventID
FROM EventTag
GROUP BY EventID
HAVING
   Sum(CASE WHEN TagID IN (1, 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= @NumTags
```

so this will find all events that both the tags exist in (this allows for instances where those two tags exist along with any additional tags)

Comment: This will potentially return false positives in the case where an event id has duplicate tags - e.g. (EventId,TagId) contains (1,1) and (1,1).

Comment: i've gone with the assumption that events don't get duplicate tags. I don't think that is unreasonable. I am stuggling to think of a situation where a duplicate tags would be useful (given the information in the problem)

Comment: the tags wouldn't be duplicate because you would have a unique constraint on the Event, Tag combination in the mapping.  This is an interesting solution.

Comment: @nitefrog i'd encourage you to look at the solution of that other question - it goes into more detail about potential optimization as well

Comment: Thank you. One thing is that the tags will not be know until later. Since you cannot use a select in the in clause, the query would have to be dynamic, which might be a killer.  The solution above however is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for when you do not know the tags before hand.

Load the tags into a table variable and get the total count:

```
select @iCount = COUNT(*) from @Tags;
```

Then write your normal query and slam those results into a table variable:

```
insert into @EventTags(IsSet, EventId)
    select distinct CASE WHEN TagID IN (select ID from @Tags) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
           e.EventId
        from  Event_Tag e
            inner join @Tags t on t.ID = e.TagId
```

Then to get back only Events that have ALL matching tags, not just ones that are in the selection, but ALL you do this:

```
select * 
    from Event_Tag e
    inner join @Tags t on t.ID = e.TagId
        where e.EventId in 
              (  select EventId 
                    from @EventTags
                        group by EventId
                            having count(EventId) = @iCount
              )
```

Only bring back tags that have all tags associated.

Thank you again everyone for the ideas!  Greatly appreciated all the feedback!

Comment: Beno's answer doesn't work when the list of "tags" is dynamic, that being the user can use a UI to select them because you can't perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery. With that said, your code is slightly off in the fact that you also need the TagID on the table variable @EventTags otherwise there will be a single record for EventID regardless of the number of tags you use. That change fixed the bug and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to inner join the two tables, as follows

`SELECT * FROM Events INNER JOIN MapTable ON MapTable.EventId=Events.EventID WHERE MapTable.TagID=1 AND MapTable.TagID=3`

Comment: This caters for only one tag matching, not both.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way to write it but this will give you what you are looking for:

```
select *
from event e
where exists(select * from maptable where eventid = e.eventid and tagid = 1) and exists(select * from maptable where eventid = e.eventid and tagid = 3)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. He wants the items from the Events table that have specifics tags.

Comment: @DBM, totally misread it, thought he only wanted to select from the mappingtable, though I wasn't sure why. Updated to select from event table

Comment: @Jimmie doesn't work.  It still bring back records that have only one of all selected.  I just ran it in TSQL.  It does not bring back records that have ALL selected tags.

Comment: @Jimmie  it is for a weird requirement.  I was hoping to do it all in TSQL, but it looks like I might have to check the records in the business layer...  Any other ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: @nitefrog, do you have duplicate records in the maptable? I created a few temp tables and tried it out and it works for me. Here is the SQL I used to test: http://pastebin.com/tDNnf2i7

Comment: @Jimmie No, the map has a unique constraint on the two columns.